class path resource [google-client-secret.json] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Error: "class path resource [google-client-secret.json] cannot be opened because it does not exist" i checked my file google-client-secret.json is src/main/resources folder but it give me error in prod env but stag env it work Please, give me solution any one.
ClassPathResource cPR= new ClassPathResource("google-client-secret.json");
in spring boot.
I want to Resolve this Error.

Is the json file also in the jar you use in prod? Does the staging and prod envs use the same jar? If yes, could staging pick up another json file instead?
